# Comparing values in a dictionary and grouping them again in Python

Tags: python

In python, i have this dictionary :

```
dict = {'key1':[a,b,c] , 'key2':[1,2,3], 'key3':[a,b,c]}
```

I need to group the keys **with the same value** (lists in this case) together in order to get a new dictionary:

```
res = {'group1':[key1,key3], 'group2':[key2]}
```

How can i do this in a easy/comprehensive way?

Comment: The answer by Robert Rossney there applies here too.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want (probably due to the use lists as values and the renaming of the values to `groupN`), Do you want an inverse mapping where each of your original values maps to a list of all the key pointing to that value?

Comment: Since your values are *lists*, you cannot directly use them as dictionary keys; converting them to tuples would allow you to represent the group in immutable form suitable as dictionary keys however.